# Can the cocycle $f_{ij}$ not be zero when $U_i=U_j$?

Tags: complex-analysis, homology-cohomology, riemann-surfaces

I am reading the book GTM 81 `Lectures on Riemann Surfaces' written by Otto Forster. I am confused about the definition of cochains and cocycles, when I read Section $\textbf{14.8}$ on page 115:

`Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topology space, $Y\in\tau(X)$, and $\mathscr{F}$ be a sheaf of abelian group on $X$. For every open covering $\mathcal{U}=(U_i)_{i\in I}$ of $X$, $\mathcal{U}\cap Y:=(U_i\cap Y)_{i\in I}$ is an open covering of $Y$. The natural restriction mapping $\phi:Z^1(\mathcal{U},\mathscr{F})\rightarrow Z^1(\mathcal{U}\cap Y,\mathscr{F})$ induces a homomorphism $H^1(\mathcal{U},\mathscr{F})\rightarrow H^1(\mathcal{U}\cap Y,\mathscr{F})$...' $\qquad\qquad(0)$

$\textbf{My question is how to define $\phi:Z^1(\mathcal{U},\mathscr{F})\rightarrow Z^1(\mathcal{U}\cap Y,\mathscr{F})$.}$

For each $f\in Z^1(\mathcal{U},\mathscr{F})$, I want to define $\phi(f)$ by
\begin{equation}[\phi(f)]_{ij}:=f_{ij}|_{U_i\cap U_j\cap Y}.\qquad(1)\end{equation}

However, for fixed $i,j$, if $Y=U_i\cap U_j$, then $U_i\cap Y=Y=U_j\cap Y$ and by (1) we know that
$$[\phi(f)]_{ij}\neq[\phi(f)]_{ji}\qquad\qquad (2)$$
can be hold sometimes:
For example, $U_i,U_j,U_k\in\tau(\mathbb{R})$, $X=U_i\cup U_j\cup U_k$, $\mathcal{U}=\{U_i,U_j,U_k\}$, $\mathscr{F}$ be the sheaf of smooth functions over $X$, and $f\in B^1(\mathcal{U},\mathscr{F})$. Let $g\in C^0(\mathcal{U},\mathscr{F})$ with $g_i\neq g_j$ on $Y$, and $f:=\delta g$. Then $f_{ij}=g_i-g_j\neq g_j-g_i=f_{ji}$ on $Y$.

Since the definition of cochains in GTM81 is not clear enough for me (on page 96):
$$C^1(\mathcal{U},\mathscr{F}):=\prod_{(i_0,...,i_q)\in I^{q+1}}\mathscr{F}(U_{i_0}\cap\cdots\cap U_{i_q}),$$ I find another definition of cochains from `'Analytic Function Theory of Several Variables' written by Junjiro Noguchi (on page 74):

`Denote
$$N_q(\mathcal{U}):=\{\sigma=(U_0,...,U_q):U_i\in\mathcal{U}\}.$$
A map $$f:\in \sigma\in N_q(\mathcal{U})\rightarrow f(\sigma)\in\Gamma(|\sigma|,\mathscr{F})$$ satisfying the alternating property
$$f(U_0,...,U_i,....,U_j,...,U_q)=-f(U_0,...,U_j,....,U_i,...,U_q)$$
is called an $q$-cochain.'

In the sense of Noguchi's definition, if $U_i=U_j=:U$ then for each $f\in C^0(\mathcal{U},\mathscr{F})$, we have
$$f_{ij}=f(U_i,U_j)=f(U,U)=f(U_j,U_i)=f_{ji}.\qquad (In\ fact\ by\ alternative\ property,\ f_{ij}=0.)$$
It is a contradiction to (2).

I would like to know：

a). Is the definition (1) wrong? What is the corrected one?

b). Do the cochains $f_{ij}$ depend on the index $i\in I$, not $U_i$, in GTM81?

c). Is there a book for cochains with a detailed definition?

———————————————————————————————————————————————————

(Not sure) I think may be two book define $H^1(\mathcal{U},\mathscr{F})\rightarrow H^1(\mathcal{U}\cap Y,\mathscr{F})$ by different ways. I just see Lemma 3.4.7 from Noguchi's book:

Assume that $\mathcal{V}$ is a refinement of $\mathcal{U}$ by two maps $\mu:\mathcal{V}\rightarrow\mathcal{U}$ and $v:\mathcal{V}\rightarrow\mathcal{U}$. Then $$\mu^*=v^*:H^q(\mathcal{U},\mathscr{F})\rightarrow H^q(\mathcal{V},\mathscr{F}).$$ Here $\mu :\mathcal{V}\rightarrow\mathcal{U}$ is a map satisfies $V\subset\mu (V)$, for each $V\in\mathcal{V}$ and
$$\mu^* :f\in C^q(\mathcal{U},\mathscr{F})\rightarrow C^q(\mathcal{V},\mathscr{F})$$
is defined by
$$\mu^*(f)(V_0,...,V_q)=f(\mu(V_0,...,V_q))|_{V_0\cap...\cap V_q}.$$

In Noguchi's sense, $C^1(\mathcal{U},\mathscr{F})\rightarrow C^1(\mathcal{U}\cap Y,\mathscr{F})$ is depended on the choice of the map $\mu$ of refinements. However, $H^1(\mathcal{U},\mathscr{F})\rightarrow H^1(\mathcal{U}\cap Y,\mathscr{F})$ is not.

I do not sure what is Forster's method.

---

I think maybe the word `natural' in $(0)$ confused me. The restriction map $\phi$ may be induced by one of the refining maps $\mu:\mathcal{U}\cap Y\rightarrow\mathcal{U}$. Then the methods of the two books coincide.

Comment: According to p.97, of course you should not expect $[\varphi (f)]_{j,k} = [\varphi(f)]_{k,j}$; instead $[\varphi (f)]_{j,k} = -[\varphi(f)]_{k,j}$ is the goal.

Comment: In the sense of Noguchi, when $U_j\cap Y=U_k\cap Y$, it must be $[\phi(f)]_{j,k}=[\phi(f)]_{k,j}=0$. I am not sure about that in GTM 81.

Comment: Why would it have to be $0$ if $U_j\cap Y=U_k\cap Y$?

Comment: In Noguchi's sense, $[\phi(f)]_{i,j}=[\phi(f)](U_i\cap Y,U_j\cap Y)=[\phi(f)](U_j\cap Y,U_i\cap Y)=[\phi(f)]_{j,i}$. And since $\phi(f)\in Z^1(\mathcal{U}\cap\mathscr{F})$, $\phi(f)$ is alternate i.e. $[\phi(f)]_{i,j}=-[\phi(f)]_{j,i}$ (it is also proved in GTM 81 from $\delta [\phi(f)]=0$, see Page 97). By above two equations, we have  $[\phi(f)]_{i,j}=[\phi(f)]_{j,i}=0$.

Comment: The first row of equality is not true. It’s true that $[\phi(f)]_{i,j}$ and $[\phi(f)]_{j,i}$ are both elements of $\mathcal{F}(U_i\cap U_j\cap Y)$, but that doesn’t mean that they have to be equal. In Noguchi’s sense, the only thing you know is that $[\phi(f)]_{i,j}=-[\phi(f)]_{j,i}$.

Comment: No, in Noguchi's sense, $[\phi(f)]$ is a map from $N_1 (\mathcal{U})$ to $\cup_{V\in\tau(X)}\mathscr{F}(V)$. $[\phi(f)]_{i,j}$ is defined by $[\phi(f)](U_i\cap Y, U_j\cap Y)$. If we write $W=U_i\cap Y=U_j\cap Y$, then $[\phi(f)]_{i,j}=[\phi(f)](W,W)$, so is $[\phi(f)]_{j,i}$.

Comment: In Noguchi's sense, $[\phi(f)]_{i,j}$ is indeed not depended on the index $i,j$. It is only dependent on $U_i\cap Y$ and $U_j\cap Y$. So if $U_i\cap Y=U_j\cap Y$, $[\phi(f)]_{i,j}$ has no different from $[\phi(f)]_{i,i}$.

Comment: In Noguchi’s definition it is said that if we have a cover $\mathcal{U}=\{U_i \ | \ i\in I\}$, then $N^q(\mathcal{U})=\{\sigma=(U_0,\dots,U_q) \ | \ U_i \in \mathcal{U}\}$ which is the same as taking $q+1$ long sequences of the indexing set $I$. So a cochain just maps a sequnce $(i_0,\dots,i_q)$ to $\mathcal{F}(U_{i_0}\cap\dots \cap U_{i_q})$. So it is very much dependant on the indexing set.

Comment: Also, if you think about cochains as maps from the sequnces of the indexing set then the restriction map becomes clear.

Comment: You can check Page 74 for the definition. I already copy them in this question. The definition of cochain is depended on $(U_i,U_j)\in N_1(\mathcal{U})$, not index $i.j$.

Comment: You should notice that there is slight difference between $(U_{i_0},...,U_{i_q})$ and $(i_1,...,i_q)$. And Noguchi use $(U_0,...,U_q)$ in his definition, even not $(U_{i_0},...,U_{i_q})$. $0,1,...,q$ may not be in $I$, in general.

Comment: The definition in GTM 81 (on page 96) is not clear for me. If $\mathscr{F}(U_{i_0},...,U_{i_q})$ is a set as $\{a,a\}\neq \{a\}$, then the cochain is depended on the index $i,j$. Otherwise, $\mathscr{F}(U_{i_0},...,U_{i_q})$ is a set in normal sense as $\{a,a\}=\{a\}$, it also will be only depended $U_i, U_j$.

Comment: I think I understand now and you are right, I misunderstood Noguchi’s definition. The definition in $(1)$ isn’t wrong tho. You just have to look at cochains as maps from sequnces  of the index set.

Comment: There is another definition of (1) by both Noguchi and GTM 81. The $\phi$ is defined by the refining map: Since $\mathcal{U}\cap Y$ is a refinement of $\mathcal{U}$, we choose a refining map $\mu:\mathcal{U}\cap Y\rightarrow \mathcal{U}$, i.e. for each $V\in\mathcal{U}\cap Y$, we have $\mu(V)\in\mathcal{U}$ and $\mu(V)\supset V$. Then $\varphi_{\mu}(f):C^1(\mathcal{U},\mathscr{F})\rightarrow C^1(\mathcal{U}\cap,\mathscr{F})$ defined by $\phi_{\mu}(f)(V,W)=f(\mu(V),\mu(W))$. This map $\phi_{\mu}$ is dependent on the selection of $\mu$.

Comment: However, by Lemma 3.4.7 in Noguchi or Lemma 12.3 in GTM 81, we know that the map $H^1(\mathcal{U},\mathscr{F})\rightarrow H^1(\mathcal{U}\cap,\mathscr{F})$ induced by $\phi_\mu$ is not dependent on $\mu$.

Comment: So I think, maybe Foester just write that sentence without detail. It makes me misunderstand that $\phi$ is induced by the restriction $U_i\mapsto U_i\cap Y$. Indeed, it should be induced by a map $U_i \cap Y \mapsto U_{j_i}$ (i.e. the refining map $\mu$).